# How do I loop through a model and save that to an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a mailer that checks for all users that meet a certain criteria.

If that criteria is true, I'm trying to do a do loop, and return the result into an array.

I'm then trying to use that to loop through that array and send an email to each email in the array.

I tried assigning the variable 'emails' to this array where I'm passing this code in

```
emails = [User.where(:state => 'Arizona').each]
```

Which isn't working because when I do the following.. the emails aren't sent

```
    emails.each do |email|
      new_request(email,row).deliver_now
    end
```

Then I tried to do a loop and save those results to an variable

```
    User.where(:state => 'Arizona').each do |u|
     emails = u.email
    end
```

Yet again, when I do this following code the emails aren't sent

```
    emails.each do |email|
      new_request(email,row).deliver_now
    end
```

FYI - everything else is working just fine with the rest of my program, the emails are definitely going out fine when I don't use this code. For instance, if I  do this:

```
emails = ['a@gmail.com','b@gmail.com']
```

the array works fine, and then I can do this..

```
    emails.each do |email|
      new_request(email,row).deliver_now
    end
```

and the code email is sent to a@gmail.com and b@gmail.com. So again, the real question is, how do I loop through those users where that criteria is true, and save to an array like this so I can run this emails.each do code and get it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  User.where(:state => 'Arizona').each do |u|
     emails = u.email
  end
```

In the above logic, in every iteration, the emails will be overwritten with the iteration email.

You have to insert the emails in an array to make the logic as expected.

```
emails = []
User.where(state: 'Arizona').each do |u|
  emails << u.email # To insert the user email into the array
end
```

You can also try to debug the values in the array whenever you face issues in logic.

```
   User.where(:state => 'Arizona').each do |u|
      emails = u.email
      p emails, "emails" # To check the value stored in the emails.
   end
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was trying to do. THank you so much

Comment: @Gregory Ostermayr's solution is more optimal. The will just select the email from the DB instead of selecting all the columns.

Answer (score 3):

Just use pluck

```
User.where(:state => 'Arizona').pluck(:email)
=>  ["a@gmail.com", "b@gmail.com"]
```